# Django jquery ajax image upload

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery

I'm using jquery form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started to upload images to django server side. There is no error but the image is not stored in the MEDIA_ROOT path. I've tried various techniques(tried plugins) for the past 2 days but nothing is working. Below I've given everything to make it easy for you.

My HTML code:

```
<form id="uploadform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="background/">
<input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
```

Javascript code:

https://gist.github.com/2377516

Django Models.py:

```
class BackgroundModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds')
```

Django views.py:

```
    def backgroundview(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            b = request.POST.get('photoimg')        
        try:
            g = BackgroundModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except BackgroundModel.DoesNotExist:
            bm = BackgroundModel(background=b)
            bm.user = request.user
            bm.save()
        else:
            g.background = b
            g.save()
        return HttpResponse("")
```

Django settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nirmal/try/files/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/files/'
```

Django urls.py:

```
url(r'^cover/$', login_required(direct_to_template), {'template': 'cover.html'}),
url(r'^cover/background/$', 'cover.views.backgroundview'),
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are in request.FILES not request.POST.  You aren't seeing any errors for this because your are never confirming that `b` actually got a value, though I'm surprised you're not seeing an error for background cannot be null.

Additionally you should try using a ModelForm for this.  It will wrap up a lot of the behavior you're having to code in.

Comment: Could you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150301/django-model-has-no-attribute-committed