# Jquery - updating Background css

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery

I'm using Jquery form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm to upload images through ajax to the server side programmed in Django. When the image is uploaded it automatically changes the background to that image. Everything is perfect(the images get stored in the database and the response is return) but how to update the css with that responseText.

Here is my javascript code: https://gist.github.com/2381991

Django response:

```
 url('home/nirmal/try/files/background/monalisa.jpg')
```

Django views.py:

```
@login_required
def backgroundview(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = BackgroundModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                g = BackgroundModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
            except BackgroundModel.DoesNotExist:
                data = form.save(commit=False)
                data.user = request.user
                data.save()
            else:
                g.background = request.FILES['background']
                g.save()
            return HttpResponse("url('"+g.background.url+"')")
    else:
        form = BackgroundModelForm()
        return render_to_response("cover.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I don't know how to update the css: background-image: url()  in jquery.
Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the showResponse callback of the jQuery form plugin, just select the element you would like to apply the background image to, and use the .css method to set the background image:

```
$("#some_element_id").css("backgroundImage", "url('/relative/address/to/image.jpg')");
```

Note: You will need to use a path to the image that is relative to the web root, not to your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

First, what mimetype of response your client-side jQuery expects? You code returns `text/html` in `HttpResponse` and you could [`.css('background-image', response_data)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Secondly, `g.background.url` looks incorrect, what's your `MEDIA_URL` in settings?

Furthermore, please check your question [Model has no attribute _committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150301/django-model-has-no-attribute-committed), `g.background = request.FILES['background']` here does not check image type and could allow any type of file to be uploaded and stored.

Comment: Can I use this g.background = form.save(commit=False).background for ModelForm? How to check Imagetype?

Comment: @mk update `MEDIA_URL` to `'/files/'`, `MEDIA_ROOT` to `'/home/try/files'` as it is an absolute path.

Comment: How can I check image type in Model Form?

Comment: @mk ModelForm uses [forms.ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield) automatically for `models.ImageField`, to do checks

Comment: @mk refs comment in settings.py: "URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a trailing slash.". Also, `MEDIA_URL` must be an URL, both '/files/' or `'http://localhost:8000/files/'` are OK, but on production you need to generate URLs that visitor could access, for example `http://example.com/files/` instead of localhost